# Angular 2+ pipe to append zeroes and a comma

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to append 3 zeroes to an entered value via a pipe?

For example, if the user types 1, the displayed value you would be 1,000.

Or 99 -> 99,000

I tried messing around with the [Number pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe), but I can't get it to add the correct number of zeroes, or to use a comma.

Is the best way to do this with a custom pipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct and default way since angular 4:

```
<p>{{99 | number:'1.3-3'}}</p>
<!--output '99.000'-->
```

> digitInfo is a string which has a following format: 
>   {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}

`minIntegerDigits` is the minimum number of integer digits to use. `Defaults to 1`.

`minFractionDigits` is the minimum number of digits after fraction. `Defaults to 0`.

`maxFractionDigits` is the maximum number of digits after fraction. `Defaults to 3`.

---

Since angular 5 or 6 (not sure) you could also provide a **culture**.

```
<p>{{99 | number:'1.3-3':CultureType.de_DE}}</p>
<!--output '99,000'-->
```

To use different cultures, do not forget to import the locales.

```
import { registerLocaleData } from "@angular/common";

import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeNl from '@angular/common/locales/nl';
import localeEnGb from '@angular/common/locales/en-GB';
import localeEnUs from '@angular/common/locales/en';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, CultureType.Development);
registerLocaleData(localeFr, CultureType.fr_FR);
registerLocaleData(localeNl, CultureType.nl_NL);
registerLocaleData(localeEnGb, CultureType.en_GB);
registerLocaleData(localeEnUs, CultureType.en_US);
registerLocaleData(localeDe, CultureType.de_DE);

export class CultureType {
    public static readonly Development: 'xh-ZA' = 'xh-ZA';
    public static readonly de_DE: 'de-DE' = 'de-DE';
    public static readonly nl_NL: 'nl-NL' = 'nl-NL';
    public static readonly fr_FR: 'fr-FR' = 'fr-FR';
    public static readonly en_GB: 'en-GB' = 'en-GB';
    public static readonly en_US: 'en-US' = 'en-US';
}
```

---

You want to **format a number** with a culture in a function, this is possible since angular 6:

```
import { formatNumber, getLocaleNumberSymbol, NumberSymbol } from "@angular/common";

/**
 * DigitsInfo:
 * {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
 * 1.2-2 => 1,00
 */
public formatNumber(num: number, digitsInfo: string): string {
    const culture: string = this.languageService.getCulture();
    return formatNumber(num, culture, digitsInfo);
}
```

---

You want to **parse a string to a number** again:

```
import { formatNumber, getLocaleNumberSymbol, NumberSymbol } from "@angular/common";

public parseStringNumber(str: string): number | null {
    if (!str) {
        return null;
    }

    const culture: string = this.languageService.getCulture();
    const decimalSeparator: string = getLocaleNumberSymbol(culture, NumberSymbol.Decimal);
    const groupSeparator: string = getLocaleNumberSymbol(culture, NumberSymbol.Group);
    const decimalSeparatorRegex = new RegExp('\\' + decimalSeparator, 'g');
    const groupSeparatorRegex = new RegExp('\\' + groupSeparator, 'g');
    const normalizedString = str.replace(groupSeparatorRegex, '').replace(decimalSeparatorRegex, '.');

    return parseFloat(normalizedString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Custom Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customCurrency'
})
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let x = value.toString() + '000';
    var lastThree = x.substring(x.length - 3);
    var otherNumbers = x.substring(0, x.length - 3);
    if (otherNumbers != '')
      lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") +    lastThree;
    return res;
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgkqk3

Answer (score 0):

@Chellapan has given the right answer, Mine just shows if you want only to append ",000" to every number displayed.

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'customNumber'
})
export class CustomNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let x = `${value},000`
    return res;
  }

}
```